# adding variable in find function not working

Tags: excel, vba

I added variables to `FIND` function and it is not working and I am getting error.

```
 ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1002) = "=IFERROR(FIND(&value&,&Copyrange&),0)"
```

I tried :

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1002) = "=IFERROR(FIND(&value,&Copyrange),0)"
```

And

```
 ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1002) = "=IFERROR(FIND(value,Copyrange),0)"
```

What has to be done?

Comment: What exactly is in `value` and `Copyrange` ?  i.e. what types of variable are they?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add quotes to the none variables

```
"=IFERROR(FIND(" & value & "," & Copyrange & "),0)"
```

Comment: I'm assuming value is supposed to be a variable.

Comment: Yes me too, but if it's a string-type variable then the final formula needs quotes around the value.